# linear homogeneous periodic equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I'm having trouble with the following problem:

Consider a linear homogeneous equation in the plane:

$x'(t)=A(t)x(t)$ (1)

Assume the matrix $A(t)$ has period $T$, in other words $A(t+T)=A(t)$. Show that if there is an periodic solution of (1) with period T and containing the origin in the interior of the orbit, then every solution of (1) is periodic with period T.

Moreover, find counter examples in higher dimensions.

Any hints? References?

Thanks

Comment: Is it $x' = Ax$?

Comment: yes, it was misprint. thank you

Comment: No reaction to the answer below? Why?

Answer (score 1):

Think geometrically: the orbit of a periodic solution is a closed curve surrounding the origin. If you scale it by $\lambda$ and let $\lambda $ run over all positive numbers, you will cover the plane (minus the origin). By linearity, all these rescaled curves are also orbits of the equation. There is no room left for any non-periodic solutions, since solution curves do not intersect.

A counterexample in 3D is easy to find: take something periodic in 2D and add something non-periodic in the third variable. Like $\frac{d}{dt}(x,y,z)= (-y,x,z)$. The solutions with $z=0$ are still periodic, but others are not.